# "-Weverything" puts a "Varargs argument missing, but tolerated as an extension" warning at each NSAssert

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, llvm, clang

After I added the new `-Weverything` to Clang's `other warning flags`, I started getting this warning for all of my **NSAsserts**:

```
Varargs argument missing, but tolerated as an extension
```

How can I fix this or, alternatively, suppress this warning?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you really want to avoid this warning, stick a `nil` as an extra argument. It appears that `-Wpedantic` doesn't like having a varargs argument with no value, so if you have `NSAssert(condition, @"static string")` you're not providing an argument for the varargs spot (`NSAssert` looks like `NSAssert(condition, format, ...)`). By sticking `nil` on the end you're providing a value for the varargs argument but there's no cost to it.

Comment: Is there a specific `-wno-whatever` for this?

Comment: @StevenFisher: I'm pretty sure it comes straight from `-pedantic`, without an individual warning flag.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't think there was, but I thought I should ask. This warning would be an ideal candidate for excluding after enabling `-Weverything`, but there's without a specific flag it can't really be done. There's no `-Wno-pedantic`. (Which strikes me as deeply funny for some reason.)

Comment: rdar://12052049, for posterity.

Comment: `-Wno-pedantic` apparently now exists in Xcode 4.5/Apple LLVM 4.1.